# What is wrong with this argument?

Tags: general-topology

Let $E \subset S$. Suppose $E$ is connected. Since $E$ is open, $E^{0} = E$. Hence $E^{0}$ is also connected.

I was thinking that it is not true because $E^{0}$ has no meaning unless we specify which topology we are considering. If we consider $E^{0}$ in the induced topology in $E$ relative to $S$, then $E^{0} = E$ is true because $E$ is open in $E$. However, if we consider $E^{0}$ in the topology of $S$, then $E^{0} \ne E$ because $E$ is not open in $S$.

Comment: What are you trying to prove? I don't get it

Comment: I know that in general $E$ is connected does not necessarily imply that $E^{0}$ is connected. (Consider two closed disks intersection at 1 point in $\mathbb{R^{2}}$.) My first argument seemingly proved it.

Comment: Why is $E$ open?

Comment: The closed disks dont fit in the argument "Since E is open"

Comment: Because E is connected. So the only set in E that are open are E and the empty set. We are looking at the induced topology on E relative to S.

Comment: When $S = \mathbb{R}$ there are many connected subsets that are not open, for example $E=[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful not to mix up open and relatively open sets:

- A topological space $S$ is connected if the only clopen subsets are the empty set and the space itself.
- A subset $E$ of a topological space $S$ is connected if it is a connected topological space under the induced subspace topology.
- A subset $U$ of a subspace $E$ of a topological space $S$ is open if it can be written as $U=E\cap V$ where $V$ is an open subset of $S$. If one needs to speak about open sets of both $S$ and its subspace $E$, it is common to get rid of the ambiguity by calling the latter "relatively open", or to name the topologies explicitly.
- The interior $E^o$ of a subset $E$ of a topological space $S$ is the largest open subset of $E$.

Note that there are typically way less open subsets contained in $E$ than there are open sets in the subspace topology induced on $E$. For exmaple, it holds for *any* subset $E$ of $S$ that $E$ is open under the induced topology!